# Strange behaviour from Font awesome 5

Tags: font-awesome-5

I am new to the use of Font Awesome (using v5 at the moment), and I have come across something strange on my page.
I have the reference to Font Awesome in my  tags:

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

I have also successfully used icons on my pages of my site, however, in one case, I only get three empty square where the icons should appear.
The code for the offending items is as follows:

```
  <div class="social">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/RadioVlaanderenNationaal/" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-facebook fa-4x"></i></a><a href="http://twitter.com/RadioVlNationaa"
      target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-twitter fa-4x"></i></a><a href="http://youtube.com/user/RadioVlaanderenNatio"
      target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-youtube fa-4x"></i></a>
    </div>
```

The strange thing is, I put, as a means of test, an icon elsewhere in the same page (just with the  tags) and it worked with no issue at all.

I assume it has something to do with the hyperlink, but what?
As I said, anywhere else on my site, the icons work good as gold.
Could someone help me out, please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is insufficient code in your question to reproduce the bug: and please do not link to external sites because they are subjected to link rot, making the question unhelpful to future users. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, concrete and verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You never included the image tags, it are `li` tags that are empty on the actual page.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know about the external site, will remove that. I noticed I grabbed the wrong code, it is now adjusted with the code referring to the font awesome icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had mistake "`fas`" it should "`fab`":

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="social">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/RadioVlaanderenNationaal/" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook fa-4x"></i></a><a href="http://twitter.com/RadioVlNationaa"
      target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter fa-4x"></i></a><a href="http://youtube.com/user/RadioVlaanderenNatio"
      target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-youtube fa-4x"></i></a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Hanif. That was the only solution I did not try. Never knew it would make that much difference, since on other places simply "fa" just worked. Thank you ever so much.

Comment: @user3592769 please accept my answer if it is work for you. :)

Comment: Sorry, Hanif. I am not fully familiar with this forum yet. I have accepted your answer as it solved my problem. Thank you so much once again.

Comment: @user3592769 thanks and I know you are newbie there :)